# ¿Cómo sumar la cantidad de registros de una tabla usando eloquent en laravel?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

Tengo una tabla llamada cities, estructura:

```
id - city - id_province
```

tabla provinces, estructura:

```
id - province
```

quiero poder sumar la cantidad de ciudades que contiene una provincia y tambien imprimir en pantalla el nombre de cada provincia, ejemplo:

`Buenos aires (12)` -> doce es la cantidad de ciudades

Las tablas ya están relacionadas, mi controlador:

```
public function cities()
{
    $results= Province::join("cities","provinces.id","=","cities.province_id")
                    ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as a_count'))
                    ->first();
    return view('web/cities', compact('results'));
}
```

Comment: añade la estructura de las tablas y la query que lleves al momento

Comment: Edité la pregunta y agregué la información que me solicitas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mi parecer ya casi tienes la consulta, solo te falta agrupar por el nombre de la provincia; por que se supone que deseas obtener no solo el nombre de cada una de estas; sino que deseas tener el total de ciudades que cada provincia tiene

**CÓDIGO**

```
public function cities()
{
  $results = Province::join('provinces.id', '=', 'cities.id_province')
             ->selectRaw('count(cities.city) as Total')
             ->groupBy('provinces.province', 'DESC')
             ->get();
}
```

**OBSERVACIONES**

1. El `JOIN` lo tienes mal escrito, dene tener el id o llave primaria y después igualarlo con la llave foránea de la segunda tabla
2. Yo prefiero usar el método `selectRaw()` que me ayuda a hacer operaciones a nivel de SQL puro para poder hacer el `COUNT`
3. Posterior, hago uso de `GORUP BY` para agrupar por el nombre de la provincia
4. Fijate que al `COUNT` le agregué un alias llamado `Total` el cual será el nombre de columna que uses para obtener ese valor en tu vista

Comment: Me funcionó bien, gracias. Sólo que me trae este array: 
[{"Total":1},{"Total":4},{"Total":1},{"Total":1},{"Total":2},{"Total":1}]  cómo hago para acceder al nombre de la ciudad? no están en el arreglo. La cantidad corresponde a las ciudades, pero no tengo el nombre de las ciudades en el array.

Comment: Si intento imprimir el nombre de la ciudad: {{ $results->city}} me dice que no existe la propiedad city, con {{ $results->total }} me funciona

Comment: Ya lo solucioné, gracias. Incluí la tabla city en el selectRaw

Comment: Tengo otra duda y la publiqué en otro post para evitar mezclar temas acá, si pudieras ayudarme con eso también, te agradecería